# Poor battery life with Intel i7

Tags: power-management, intel

I have an Asus K55VD laptop (Intel i7-3610QM, Intel HD-4000), and have noticed poor battery life when using Ubuntu: ~3hrs.  This runtime is with the screen at minimum brightness, the processor scaled all the way down, pm-powersave set to "true", and the wifi power-management on.  Does anyone here know how to decrease the power consumption?  I've gotten the same battery life on 12.04, 12.10, and even raring pre-release.  Are there some sort of Intel-specific power-management tools available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try laptop-mode-tools. And also try these grub parameters: pcie_aspmi=force i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vbankoffdelay=1

This (and bumblebee, but this is not your case) worked very well for me.

Comment: Good advice, my battery life jumped considerably just with laptop-mode-tools.  However, when I applied the GRUB parameters you suggested and update-grubbed and rebooted, it knocked down the performance a lot, and no longer allowed 3D effects in Unity...

Answer (score 0):

no, you also must use bumblebee. i have the same your laptop, with bumblebee  i have a 1 hours plus for battery time life